# Как разбудить устройство в BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcast-receiver

**Условие:** Есть приложение которое, в определённый момент, должно пробуждать устройство (экран устройства должен включится) и показывать уведомление. Работа осуществляется через BroadcastReceiver.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent)
{
    //Будим девай
    wakeDevice(context)

    //Вызываем функцию показа уведомления
    makeBarNotification(context)
}
```

Всё, что касается пробуждения устройства выведено в отдельную функцию. Код ниже:

```
private fun wakeDevice(context: Context)
{
    //Создаём Power manager
    val powerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    //Создаём WakeLock
    val myWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, "MyApp:NotificationWakelockTag")
    //Указываем длительность работы (В данном случае 5 секунд)
    myWakeLock.acquire(5 * 1000L)
    //Запускаем WakeLock
    myWakeLock.release()
}
```

> В manifest'e прописал строчку: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

**Проблема:** Устройство не пробуждается и вылетает ошибка: "`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify a valid wake lock level.`" 
 указывающая на строчку, где я создаю WakeLock (`val myWakeLock = ...`)

**Предположение:** Вероятно проблема в  `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`. Этот код рекомендуют использовать взамен `PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` вот тут: [источник](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK)

**Вопрос:** Как тогда разбудить устройство в ВroadcastReceiver'e если код `PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` - "deprecated", а код `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` приводит к ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны использовать один из вариантов при вызове newWakeLock

1. [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)
2. [FULL_WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK)
3. [SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK)
4. [SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK)

Ресурс: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555630/specify-valid-wake-lock-level

Comment: [PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK was deprecated in API level 15.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK) Остальные, приведённые вами варианты, не подходят мне по характеристикам, причём ещё двое из них также "deprecated".